# java.lang.NullPointerException - ResultSet

Tags: java, connection, nullpointerexception, resultset

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.cacheRowAt(ScrollableResultSet.java:2086)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.isValidRow(ScrollableResultSet.java:2060)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.next(ScrollableResultSet.java:347)
    at website.web.InboxReader.getkeywordImportance(InboxReader.java:832)
    at website.web.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:54)
```

There are `53` rows in `Mail` table and `1` row in `keyword` table. On debugging, as soon as the line is executed `kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE + 1.0 WHERE SKEYWORD = '" + s2 + "'");` it goes again to `keyword set.next()` and throws the exception.

Here is the code:

```
Connection connection = connectToDatabase();
        Statement mstmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String s1,s2;
        ResultSet mailset = mstmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from MAIL");
        System.out.println("hello in getImportance beg"); 
        //mailset.beforeFirst();
        while(mailset.next())
        {               
            System.out.println("hello in first while"); 
            Statement kstmt = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet keywordset = kstmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM KEYWORD");
            while(keywordset.next())
            {
                s1=mailset.getString("SUBJECT");
                System.out.println("Subject: "+s1);
                s2=keywordset.getString("SKEYWORD");
                System.out.println("Keyword: "+s2);
                if(s1.contains(s2))
                {
                    System.out.println("hello in if");  
                    kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE + 1.0 WHERE SKEYWORD = '" + s2 + "'");  

                }
            }
            keywordset.close();
        }
        mailset.close();
        connection.close();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run it in a debugger? (Or at least, which line is 832?)

Comment: @BenvanGompel while(keywordset.next())

Comment: I'm not a DB expert, but aren't you misusing `kstmt`?

Comment: please update with full exceptio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you take a look at this line which seems to be problematic:

`kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE ='" + (keywordset.getFloat("IMPORTANCE") + 1.0) + "'");`

You should double check the call

`keywordset.getFloat("IMPORTANCE")`

This mostlikely due to the fact the the column Importance is empty for the record or that the column might not exist. Just to debug you try with

`keywordset.getFloat(0);`

or which ever id of a column you know exist to see if the call works.

Have you tried removing the COMMIT statement ? Because usually unless you specify otherwise the data is automatically committed so there is no need to call a commit after your statement and if you have specified the auto_commit to false then to commit you should do `con.commit()` and not call it through an update statement

Comment: Its updating `Importance` from `0` to `1` in the table then it is throwing the exception. There is `1` row in the `keyword` table and `Importance` is defined as `Float`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that your null pointer exception it thrown when you execute `keyworset.getFload("IMPORTANCE")`  but if you just want to increment the value of the importance field in the database why not just write `UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE+1` but be careful as this will increment all the IMPORTANCE record of the keyword table since you do not have a where clause. I also would highly suggest you use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: How about this?      `kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE +" + 1.0 + "WHERE SKEYWORD = " + s2 + "'");`

Comment: Have you tried removing the COMMIT statement ? Because usually unless you specify otherwise the data is automatically committed so there is no need to call a commit after your statement and if you have specified the auto_commit to false then to commit you should do `con.commit()` and not call it through an update statement.

Comment: if you are to hard code 1 in the statement might as well hard code it in the sql statement it will create less string concatenation but your getting the idea. Also you are missing a single quote in front of s2 in your where clause

Comment: No I haven't removed Commit. Will try that and you mean `"UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE + 1.0 WHERE SKEYWORD = '"` ?

Comment: yep `kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE +1 WHERE SKEYWORD = '" + s2 + "'");`

Comment: Removed the commit statement.`if(s1.contains(s2))
     {
      System.out.println("hello in if"); 
        
      kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE + 1.0 WHERE SKEYWORD = '" + s2 + "'"); 
      
     }` Its still giving null pointer exception right after the first match is found. Its updating the value in database and then throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you isolate which row exactly is throwing the exception using debug or system.out.print statement ? And has the error stack changed ?

Comment: It goes to `keywordset.next()` after executing update statement and then throws the error.

Comment: Why are you using scrollable resultsets ? why not create them as regular statements since you do not seem to have any need to read them backward not update the records directly in the result set. Try for both statements `connection.createStatement();`

Answer (score 2):

Please see the documentation here
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

No need to call beforeFirst as you seem to expect next to behave.

```
public static void viewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = null;
    String query = "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, SALES, TOTAL from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";
    try {
      stmt = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()) {
        String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
        int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
        float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
        int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
        int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
        System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID + "\t" + price + "\t" + sales + "\t" + total);
      }
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
      JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
      if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Ya, but initially it was given null for result sets so I tried that.

Comment: yes always please check for null. Are you sure there are rows in the table?

Comment: Yes there are, `53 rows` in `Mail` table and `1 row` in `keyword` table.

Comment: When its correctly printing the value of `s1` and `s2`, why is it giving Null pointer exception?

Comment: I just checked my database. `Importance` is getting updated properly and after that it throwing the exception.

Comment: is the line keywordset.getFloat returning any values ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running it without keywordset.beforeFirst() and  mailset.beforeFirst() ? That is not required, and it might be creating an issue in ResultSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
kstmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE KEYWORD SET IMPORTANCE = IMPORTANCE + 1.0 WHERE SKEYWORD = '" + s2 + "'");
```

When this line execute in your code your keywordset `ResultSet` object will change because all execute methods will cause effect on `ResultSet`. 
All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.
 What you have to do is create a separate object of statement for running this query so that keywordset `ResultSet` won't get affected ... ...:)